# Should I change gear on my dual-spec Death Knight?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Haven't used dual-spec since just last night (yup!).
I've decided to make my tank Blood DK (85) dual spec as Frost for dps.

With that in mind, should I switch gear every time I switch the specs?
Or is the STR/STA combination good enough for both?

Also, what about weapons...  I use two-handed weapons on Blood, should I switch to two one-handed weapons?  Consider maximizing the weapon-damage spells.

What I'm trying to do is be the toughest tank when in Blood and do the most damage in Frost.
But when in Frost, I don't know if it's better to increase speed and crit over damage?

Insights and criticism welcome!

Comment: I use the addon Outfitter for switching gear when changing spec. You can easily set it up to switch to different gear sets based on current spec through use of the "Script" feature. Make a set, click the arrow next to it, and choose the script Primary Spec or Secondary Spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be fine tanking normal 5-mans in your DPS gear (*not* Heroics) but if you want to get anywhere, you will need to pick up some more gear. Look for high stamina plate pieces with Dodge, Parry, or bonus armor, and shy away from crit.

Yes, you should absolutely change your gear when going from a DPS spec to a Tank spec (or vice versa, some feral druids excluded).

Comment: Often a feral Druid will use different gear items for bear tanking and cat DPS, though sometimes it's possible to use 1 spec for both.

Comment: I actually have three sets of gear for the drooid, since I'm feral/resto. Tanking and DPS are contradictory: Tanks need hit/expertise/stam/agil/armor/dodge...

Comment: (Stupid...hit return then took too long writing the rest)...That's completely different from DPS, where you need Agil/AP/Mastery/Crit/Haste/Hit. I use only 1 spec (the feral tank spec, so my dps isn't top notch) but the gear makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: Yup. Endgame, I agree with you. But leveling up, especially through 1-60, there's not enough dedicated tanking gear to make a difference, so druids can get away with 2 specs and 1 set of gear.

Comment: I imagine that leveling 55-60 for a death knight would have much the same lack of gear options.

Comment: @Kurley -- the OP specifically mentions his death knight is level 85.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - I know that. It was only when you were trying to back up your rather bizarre comment about druids that you mentioned lower level characters. BTW, I did mark your answer up, I just found the remark about druids rather odd and maybe a little misleading.